# Provide information for the caller of a certain method with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have a method with 1 overload and I want to find out with Roslyn whether someone is calling the overload method and show a hint in that case.

The methods looks like this:

```
public void Info(string message, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
}


public void Info(string message, string secondMessage, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
}
```

If someone types for example:

```
Info("The message", secondMessage: "Second message");
```

I would like to show some information to the developer.

Is it possible to do this with Roslyn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with Roslyn?

Yes. You need to get the method symbol from the semantic model, and then use `FindReferencesAsync`

```
// Get your semantic model
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
//Or
var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync();

// Get the method you want to find references to.
// You have a lot of ways to do that, but for example:
var method = doc.GetSyntaxRootAsync().
     Result.DescendantNodes().
     OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().
     First();
//Or
var method = root.DescendantNodes().
     OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().
     First();

//Then get the symbol info of the method
var methodSymbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(method).Symbol;

// And finally
SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution).Result
```

I recommend to read about `Solution\Project\Document`, `SyntaxTree\Root\Node`, `Compilation\SemanticModel`.

Once you will understand this, it will be easily to write analyzer that to what you want. I can paste here an analyzer example, but you can find much more in the net (check the link in my comment for example).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also know, how to use this in a diagnostic analyzer for visual studio?

Comment: @Mi.Sharp When you write analyzer  \ code fix, you have a context, from the context you can get what you need (root, document, semantic model etc.). Check [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scenario, it *may* be sufficient just to add `[Obsolete]`:

```
[Obsolete("You're probably doing it wrong, neighbour", false)]
public void Info(string message, string secondMessage,
     [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
```

If you want to call it from some of your own code without the warning:

```
#pragma warning disable 0618
Info("foo", "bar", "blap");
#pragma warning restore 0618
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want to have. There should be a possibility to do this in an Analyzer so that I can control the behaviour a little bit?:)

Comment: @Mi.Sharp and I'm sure you *can* do that in an analyzer; I've never written one, though...

Comment: @Mi.Sharp You can do it with analyzer as you can see in my answer. For help with writing analyzer you can check the link in my comment. If you still have any question let me know.